# How can I start a new encoding job when CPU usage goes below 80ù?

Tags: powershell, scripting, video-encoding

I wrote a powershell script that cycles through a folder containing .mov files encoded in ffv1. Each file is being encoded to .h264 with certain parameters. after the encode, the VMAF score for that encode is being calculated and compared towards a given minimum and maximum value. If the VMAF score is within range, the next file is being encoded. If not, the file is being re-encoded with a different CRF value being higher when vmaf is above maximum and lower when VMAF is below minimum.

This all works fine but the problem is that it takes quite some time to process each file. Now I saw that CPU usages only spikes for a few seconds while an encode is in progress. My idea was to actively check for CPU usage going below 80% and start the next encoding job, basically running them parallel with probbably 3-4 at a time (a CPU spike goes for about 3 seconds and then drops for about 9).

The script I currently have is this

```
# Set the path to ffmpeg
$ffmpegPath = "C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"

# Set the input and output paths
$inputPath = "E:\encode\chunks"
$outputPath = "E:\encode\video"
$crf = 18
$vmafMin = 96
$vmafMax = 98
$crfCount = 0
$crfTotal = 0
$crfAvg = 0
$vmafCount = 0
$vmafTotal = 0
$vmafAvg = 0
New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path "E:\encode\encodinglog.txt"

write-host "Starting encoding" -ForegroundColor Yellow

# Loop through each file in the input directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $inputPath -Filter *.mov | ForEach-Object {

    # Set the starting CRF value
    $crf = $crf
    $vmafOutput = ""
    $vmafScore = $null

    # Build the output file path
    $outputFile = Join-Path $outputPath $_.Name

    # Encode the file with the current CRF value
    Write-Host "Encoding chunk $($outputFile) with CRF $crf" -ForegroundColor Green
    & $ffmpegPath -y -v quiet -stats -i $_.FullName -c:v libx264 -crf $crf -trellis 2 -b_qfactor 1 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.50 -maxrate 15000 -qmax 41gKFtogHYuTLgtmff2zbx9hk7DWS8VB612gDjf1YFPsfT66jV4UFCBNJSsUKKBpwf9y4CunA1UoucxSkm8NLtmRFxDFATc0 -g 48 -flags -loop $outputFile

    # Calculate the VMAF score
    $vmafOutput = & $ffmpegPath -i $outputFile -i $_.FullName -lavfi "libvmaf=model=path='vmaf_v0.6.1.json'" -f null - 2>&1
    
    # Extract the VMAF score from the output
    $vmafScore = [double](([regex]::Matches($vmafOutput, "VMAF score: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)").Groups)[1].Value)

    # Check if the VMAF score is below 95 or above 97
    while (($vmafScore -lt $vmafMin -or $vmafScore -gt $vmafMax) -and $crf -lt 20){

    if ($vmafScore -lt $vmafMin) {
        # Decrease the CRF value by 1 and re-encode the file

        $crf--
        Write-Host "VMAF score of $vmafScore for $($outputFile) too low. Re-encoding with CRF is $crf" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        & $ffmpegPath -y -v quiet -stats -i $_.FullName -c:v libx264 -crf $crf -trellis 2 -b_qfactor 1 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.50 -maxrate 15000 -qmax 41gKFtogHYuTLgtmff2zbx9hk7DWS8VB612gDjf1YFPsfT66jV4UFCBNJSsUKKBpwf9y4CunA1UoucxSkm8NLtmRFxDFATc0 -g 48 -flags -loop $outputFile

        # Calculate the VMAF score
        $vmafOutput = ""
        $vmafScore = $null
        $vmafOutput = & $ffmpegPath -i $outputFile -i $_.FullName -lavfi "libvmaf=model=path='vmaf_v0.6.1.json'" -f null - 2>&1
        $vmafcalc = [double](([regex]::Matches($vmafOutput, "VMAF score: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)").Groups)[1].Value)
        
        # Extract the VMAF score from the output
        $vmafScore = [double](([regex]::Matches($vmafOutput, "VMAF score: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)").Groups)[1].Value)
        
    } elseif ($vmafScore -gt $vmafMax) {

        # Increase the CRF value by 1 and re-encode the file
        $crf++
        Write-Host "VMAF score of $vmafScore for $($outputFile) too high. Re-encoding with CRF is $crf" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        & $ffmpegPath -y -stats -v quiet -i $_.FullName -c:v libx264 -crf $crf -trellis 2 -b_qfactor 1 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.50 -maxrate 15000 -qmax 41gKFtogHYuTLgtmff2zbx9hk7DWS8VB612gDjf1YFPsfT66jV4UFCBNJSsUKKBpwf9y4CunA1UoucxSkm8NLtmRFxDFATc0 -g 48 -flags -loop $outputFile

        # Calculate the VMAF score
        $vmafOutput = ""
        $vmafScore = $null
        $vmafOutput = & $ffmpegPath -i $outputFile -i $_.FullName -lavfi "libvmaf=model=path='vmaf_v0.6.1.json'" -f null - 2>&1
        $vmafcalc = [double](([regex]::Matches($vmafOutput, "VMAF score: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)").Groups)[1].Value)
        
        # Extract the VMAF score from the output
        $vmafScore = [double](([regex]::Matches($vmafOutput, "VMAF score: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)").Groups)[1].Value)
        }
    }
    Add-Content -Path "E:\encode\encodinglog.txt" -Value "$($outputFile), CRF: $crf, VMAF: $vmafScore"
    Write-Host "VMAF score of $vmafScore for $($outputFile) with CRF $crf OK. Encoding next chunk." -ForegroundColor green
    $crfCount++
    $crfTotal = $crfTotal + $crf
    $crfAvg = $crfTotal / $crfCount
    $vmafCount++
    $vmafTotal = $vmafTotal + $vmafScore
    $vmafAvg = $vmafTotal / $vmafCount
    write-host "VMAF Avg: $vmafAvg, CRF Avg: $crfAvg" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    if ($vmafAvg -lt 96) {
        $vmafMin++
        $vmafMax++
        write-host "VMAF Avg getting too low.increasing min and max VMAF to $vmafMin and $vmafMax" -foregroundColor Red
        }

    if ($crf -eq 20) {
        $crf--}
    else {$crf = $crf}
}
write-host "Encoding finished! See you soon!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Add-Content -Path "E:\encode\encodinglog.txt" -Value "VMAF Avg: $vmafAvg, CRF Avg: $crfAvg"
```

What's the most elegant solution to achieve paralel encodes? Would CPU based be the good way to go or rather run a few jobs at the same time?

How would I implement this in the current script?

I tried first with `start-job` first as suggested but that didn't really work for some reason. It started the jobs but the code within the `-scriptBlock` wasn't executed.

Comment: Only run parallel task for the number of cores in the microprocessor.  You do not get any gain in performance when you run more parallel operations than the number of cores in the micro.

Comment: Yes I get that but, they are 4 second chunks so at this point, one job takes about 10 seconds to complete at best (more when one job needs to be multiple passes because of VMAF). I was thinking if I base it on CPU usage, it wouldn't start a new job when usage isn't below a certain level.

Comment: @jdweng nonsense. that depends on what the tasks are doing.

Comment: Exactly that. One task is only going for 10 seconds.